# cURLlib/File_get_contents only loading partial data

Tags: php, css, curl, file-get-contents

So i'm doing a little project where i wanna get some data from another website. After doing some reading, i figured i should use the `cURL` lib (& `get_file_contents()`) - but it wasn't as easy as that, apparently.
In my case i want some of the data contained in a table @ http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/news/companynews
But the problem is that, its only returning part of the site to me - i'm missing all the table data, and most of the css (not that i care about the css).

So far i have tried, `simple_html_dom`, `cURL`, `file_get_contents($url)` and a couple of other parsers, and all of them seem to only return partial data. I used a couple of hours on it now, and doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

I'm currently using the code below, to retrieve the site.

```
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

and it returns me something like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyVvK.jpg
Would appreciate some help, i'm about to bash my head into something - and nobody likes to clean up blood :)

*EDIT*
So i have done some more digging, and it seems to be because most of the content on the site is loaded dynamically.

So what are my options now? i manage to get a hold of the HTTP GET request, that fetches the data - but i'm not sure what my next step are :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not do it programatically, then I'll suggest you to use any site grabber tool or download manager like softwares.

But if it is must to use code, then here is my suggestion. Get the html content using `curl` or `file_get_contents` and then replace the relative links(`/xyz/mycss.css`) into absolute(`http://www.site.com/xyz/mycss.css`) links for `javascript` and `css`. But still it will not be a 100% perfect solution.

This is not that much simple as you thought initially. You have already realized by this time.

Comment: yeah i quite quickly realized that, sadly i found no real solution to the problem - but i manage to work around it regardless.
I looked through all the HTTP requests send by the site, and manage to find the one getting the information i needed. And when i had that i simply requested it with cURL and my "problem" was solved.

But thanks for your answer regardless :)